# Handle Youtube Embed restriction

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube, webbrowser-control, embed

I'm actually developping a JARVIS assistant 
It will have a lot of module But i start with what was supposed an easy one.

the Youtube One. So my mainwindow who are fullscreen or hidden has a WebBrowser

```
    private static string GetYouTubeVideoPlayerHTML(string videoCode)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        const string YOUTUBE_URL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("    <head>");
        sb.Append("        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; height=device-height;\">");
        sb.Append("    </head>");
        sb.Append("    <body marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" leftmargin=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" style=\"overflow-y: hidden\">");
        sb.Append($"        <iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src =\"{YOUTUBE_URL}{videoCode}?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0\" frameborder = \"0\" allowfullscreen>");
        sb.Append("    </body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This return the string i use with WebBrowser.Navigate()

It work well but if the video has embeded restriction like VEVO i can't see it 
https://www.youtube.com/embed/wfN4PVaOU5Q
Exemple here
One thing tell me its possible because in this site
http://codepen.io/Jebik/pen/ZLZQwX
The embeded work like a charm.... 
So it's probably something that i don't get about this restriction.

Any idéa and solution is welcomming.
But i would rather have a legit solution like "man you must register your domain and ask the page in https" than "you can hack this security by this method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way i don't know why its works

I use a server i have to upload a webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
      var player;
      var body = document.body;
      var html = document.documentElement;
      var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
      var width = Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, 
                       html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth );
      window.onresize = resize;
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
      {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: height,
          width: width,
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'enablejsapi':1, 'iv_load_policy':3, 'modestbranding':1, 'showinfo':0},
          videoId: '<?php echo $_GET["v"]; ?>',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
          }
        });
      }
      function resize()
      {
        height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
        width = Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, 
                       html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth );
        if(player != null)
        {
          player.setSize(width, height);
        }
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function playVideo() 
      {
        player.playVideo();
      }
      function pauseVideo() 
      {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The web page Must Be acces from https
I don't exactly know why 
Maybe youtube use the certificat to know the real location of web site (checking where it is registred instead of the ip)

And after taht i change my WebBrowser.NavigateToString by a `WebBrowser.Navigate($"https://domain.fr/youtube.php?v={VideoCode}");`

In this way i have a youtube player in full screen in my WPF window and i can read most of the youtube video like VEVO limited one.

This is resolved but if anyone know why i'm curious to know